# MongoDB - document is adding with luuid

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have problem with add document to collection from C#.

I have model in my program

```
public class Object
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public long StartTimestamp { get; set; }
    public long EndTimestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And the problem is in my database. All documents are saveing with LUUID but no with CSUUID and i cannot eg. find by id

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a string type for the C# object, but with a serialization attribute:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;    

public class Object
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public long StartTimestamp { get; set; }

    public long EndTimestamp { get; set; }
}
```